# Phonegap: how to remove files from the apk file during/after build?

Tags: eclipse, cordova, apk

When I run (and build) a Phonegap application in Eclipse, I want to remove all unneccessary files afterwards from the apk that was built (temporary files, *.php files, etc.)

I made a PHP script, that does this (using ZipArchive), and it works perfectly when executing it separately, but not in a custom builder that I made. I added this builder to the end of the builders-list, but I guess while deploying the apk, it is still locked, so I can't make changes to it.

Is there any way to remove files from a Phonegap apk while running/building from Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'hook'... write a script to remove unwanted files and place it under "{projectFolder}/hook/after_build/" folder.